# php looping through an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array which contains numbers like "331,554,22" or it could be "45", lets say the array is called `$numbers`.

I want to loop through the array and for each number or entry in it, do a SQL query like

```
UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=$numbers[x]
```

Could someone help me along?

UPDATE: Also, say I store the query values in a text field in my database called `nums` and it looks like eg. "45,656,23", how would I convert that to an array format?

Comment: "331,554,22" - is this really an array, or is it a string of numbers separated by commas? If it is the latter, you will need to `explode()` it first, then you will have an array.

Just asking.

Comment: its a string, so, yeah explode i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the veriable     `"331,554,22"` is not an array (string), 
explode it first

```
$numbers = explode(',',$numbers);
```

and then.

Foreach :

```
 foreach ($numbers as $number)
        {
          //query like  SET x=1 where id=$number
        }
```

For :

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++)
    {
       //query like  SET x=1 where id=$numbers[$i]
    }
```

if x is always 1 you can use in,

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET x = 1 WHERE id  IN(" . implode(',',$numbers)  . ")"
```

and if the `$numbers` variable is string, and  `x` will be `1` for each ID, forget all of I wrote and try this only :)

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET x = 1 WHERE id  IN({$numbers})"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($numbers as $number) {
  $sql = "UPDATE some_table SET X = 1 WHERE id = ".$number
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET x=1 WHERE id IN(".implode( ",", $numbers).")";
```

> its a string, so, yeah explode i guess.

```
$query = "UPDATE members SET x=1 WHERE id IN({$numbers})";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$numbers = array(25, 658, 968, 548, 698, 365);

foreach($numbers as $number){
 echo "UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=$number\n";
}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=25 
 UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=658
 UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=968 
 UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=548 
 UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=698 
 UPDATE members SET x=1 where id=365
```